# Declaring iPhone UI with XML

Tags: iphone, ios, xml, user-interface, interface-builder

I want to create a Layout of Pages using XML, like the Interface Builder does.
Reason is, that I have a CodeGenerator and I want to generate iPhone UI's.
Is this somewhere documented, how the UI is build via xml for iOS?

I found [this](https://github.com/CRedit360/WorkflowSchema) but I would like to use the XML description from iOS, so that the user can edit the generated UI if he wants to.

I am talking only for non-games Application.